# How to specialize templated class inside other templated class?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I want to create templated class `allocator_factory` and templated `arena_allocator` inside it. As far `arena_allocator` inherits from `std::allocator` I must create specialization for `arena_allocator<void>`, but I can't.

Compiler error is: `arena_alloc.h:25:37: error: too few template-parameter-lists`

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <cstddef>


template <std::size_t Size, typename Tag>
class allocator_factory;


template <std::size_t Size, typename Tag>
class allocator_factory
{
public:
    static constexpr std::size_t size = Size;
    typedef Tag tag_type;

    template <typename T>
    class arena_allocator;
};



template <std::size_t Size, typename Tag>
class allocator_factory<Size, Tag>::arena_allocator<void> :
    public std::allocator<void>   //^ error here
{
    typedef std::allocator<void> Parent;
public:
    typedef typename Parent::value_type         value_type;
    typedef typename Parent::pointer            pointer;
    typedef typename Parent::const_pointer      const_pointer;
    typedef typename Parent::size_type          size_type;
    typedef typename Parent::difference_type    difference_type;

    typedef allocator_factory<Size,Tag> factory_type;

    template <typename U>
    struct rebind
    {
        typedef typename allocator_factory<size, tag_type>::template arena_allocator<U> other;
    };

    typedef typename Parent::propagate_on_container_move_assignment propagate_on_container_move_assignment;

    arena_allocator() throw() : Parent() {}
    arena_allocator(const arena_allocator& a) throw() : Parent(a) {}
    template <class U>
    arena_allocator(const arena_allocator<U>& a) throw() :Parent(a) {}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can specialize an enclosed template without fully specializing the enclosing one:

```
template<class T>
struct A {
    template<class U>
    struct B {};
};

template<>
template<>
struct A<int>::B<int> {}; // Okay.

template<>
template<class U>
struct A<int>::B<U*> {}; // Okay.

template<class T>
template<>
struct A<T>::B<int> {}; // error: enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized
```

---

As a work-around, extract the enclosed template into the file/namespace scope and specialize it as you please:

```
// Extracted template.
template <std::size_t Size, typename Tag, typename T>
class the_arena_allocator;

template <std::size_t Size, typename Tag>
class allocator_factory
{
public:
    static constexpr std::size_t size = Size;
    typedef Tag tag_type;

    template <typename T>
    using arena_allocator = the_arena_allocator<Size, Tag, T>;
};

// A partial specialization of the extracted template.
template <std::size_t Size, typename Tag>
class the_arena_allocator<Size, Tag, void> { /* ... */ };
```

Comment: All my moving with enclosing template is  to leave allocator as one parameter template and hide size and tag inside it

Comment: @user2807083 Your member template class is still parametrized by the enclosing template template parameters. The difference is only syntactic.